# NSDate returning wrong date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

Today is Feb 1 of 2016 and I just opened up my working app to continue my work and this shocks me.

[image]

It is a collection view of date, I didn't notice anything wrong during January because it hasn't been a month.

Here's the code,

```
func dF(someDate:NSDate) -> (String){
let monthFormat = NSDateFormatter()
let dayFormat = NSDateFormatter()
monthFormat.dateFormat = "MMM"
dayFormat.dateFormat = "D"

let aMonth = monthFormat.stringFromDate(someDate)
let aDay = dayFormat.stringFromDate(someDate)

//concatenate strings
let conString = aMonth + " " + aDay

return (conString)
}


//from today to 7th day, to be used in ScrollView
let day1 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 0, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
let day2 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -1, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
let day3 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -2, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
let day4 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -3, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
let day5 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -4, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
let day6 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -5, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
let day7 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -6, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
let titles = [dF(day1!), dF(day2!), dF(day3!), dF(day4!), dF(day5!), dF(day6!), dF(day7!)]
```

I'm expecting day1 to pass the current date to function dF and format it.

So I ran some checks to make sure I've got the correct date
Current time: Feb 1, 2016, 1:08am in my time zone

```
print(day1)
print(day2)
print(ddd)
```

Here's the result from console:

Optional(2016-01-31 17:08:47 +0000)

Optional(2016-01-30 17:08:47 +0000)

Feb 32

I'm suspecting my NSDateComponent isn't setup correctly/on par with local time zone. Any ideas?

Comment: Read the documentation for date formatting specifiers. `D` isn't what you seem to think it is for.

Comment: More than in any other area, if you think there's a bug in the handling of dates and calendars, it is most likely that the bug is in your code or that your expectations are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using the wrong specifier for the day of the month.
2. You are creating your date string the hardest way possible.

Try this:

Swift 3/4:

```
func dF(_ someDate: Date) -> String {
    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = "MMM d"
    // For a more localized format, use the following instead:
    // format.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMd")        

    let conString = format.string(from: someDate)

    return conString
}
```

Old Swift 2 answer:
    func dF(someDate:NSDate) -> (String){
        let format = NSDateFormatter()
        format.dateFormat = "MMM d"

```
    let conString = format.stringFromDate(someDate)

    return (conString)
}
```

Comment: this bugs me and I still can't solve it, would you mind to have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115936/unexpected-quirky-behavior-from-socket-io-in-swift

Comment: And I would recommend to use `format.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMd")` to set the format otherwise it won't be properly localized.

Answer (score 0):

More Swifty way to solve your problem. Works with Swift 3 and above.

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM d"
let result = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Output

```
"May 12"
```